# Can I use ${ } for array elements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The challenge is to create an "emoji" VS "emoji", but when I run this code, I get an `TypeError: 'x' is not iterable` error. (with x being the randomly generated number)

```
let fighters = ["", "", "","", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","", "", ""]

let stageEl = document.getElementById("stage")
let fightButton = document.getElementById("fightButton")

fightButton.addEventListener("click", function() {    
    const [iOne, iTwo] = Math.floor( Math.random() * fighters.length )    
    stageEl.textContent = `${fighters[iOne]} VS ${fighters[iTwo]}`
})
```

Comment: `Math.floor()` returns a number, so I'm struggling to see how it works with your destructuring / `[iOne, iTwo]`. Also, there is no reference to `x` in this code, so not sure where x is trying to iterate.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this line:

```
    const [iOne, iTwo] = Math.floor( Math.random() * fighters.length )
```

The right-hand side is giving you a number and you are trying to iterate it into two variables. See the docs for [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

The code should be:

```
    const iOne = Math.floor( Math.random() * fighters.length )
    const iTwo = Math.floor( Math.random() * fighters.length )
```

Or

```
    const getRandomInt = (length) => Math.floor( Math.random() *  length);
    const iOne = getRandomInt(fighters.length)
    const iTwo = getRandomInt(fighters.length)
```